# Is there a way to continue your test without logging in again in selenium. C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Hi this may be related to an issue I was having with the driver initiating a blank page. I'd like to get my tests flowing in a way where I don't have to login everytime. Or is that the norm? In my code below Test method LoginToWordpress() works and passes. CreateAPost() fires a blank instance of firefox. Is there a way around this?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
namespace WordpressAutomation
{
    [TestClass]
    public class WordpressTests
    {

        IWebDriver driver;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void GoToWordpress()
        {
            //Create an instance of the firefox driver.
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void LoginToWordPress()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://moodpk01.wordpress.com/wp-login.php");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_login")).SendKeys("");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_pass")).SendKeys("");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("wp-submit")).Click();
            string actualvalue = driver.FindElement(By.Id("wp-admin-bar-blog")).Text;
            Assert.AreEqual(actualvalue, "My Site");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CreateAPost()
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("wp-menu-name")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("page-title-action")).Click();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Teardown()
        {
                //driver.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this code:

```
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://moodpk01.wordpress.com/wp-login.php");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_login")).SendKeys("");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_pass")).SendKeys("");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("wp-submit")).Click();
```

in TestInitialize() method, that way, it will execute only at the start of test. Assuming you can continue with logging only once !!

Comment: Thanks. It does work I've changed my method name just to verify the login now. Works a treat.

Comment: Nice to help you out !!